npm install react-cookie error: Unsupported platform for @rollup/rollup-darwin-x64@4.28.1 on Windows
I am trying to install the react-cookie package, but I am getting the following error:
npm error code EBADPLATFORM
npm error notsup Unsupported platform for @rollup/rollup-darwin-x64@4.28.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","cpu":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","cpu":"x64"})
npm error notsup Valid os:   darwin
npm error notsup Actual os:  win32
npm error notsup Valid cpu:  x64
npm error notsup Actual cpu: x64

I am on a Windows machine with the following setup:
OS: Windows 11
CPU: x64
Here’s what I have tried:
Cleared npm cache using npm cache clean --force. Tried reinstalling the package using npm install react-cookie but still encounter the same error. Checked for platform compatibility and found that the error refers to @rollup/rollup-darwin-x64, which is for macOS, but I am on Windows. How can I resolve this error and successfully install react-cookie on my Windows system?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
